# How to save two different objects sent by the same route to the api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor

hello community I have two classes one called tax and another called tax detail, I have created a kind of form that does not work as such since I do not use the editform that is typical of blazor in that form I have the inputs to fill and in their bind-values the values to send to the database. The problem is that in the form some values come from the tax class and others from the tax class details so I don't know how to pass the object to the route that goes to the controller since it only accepts one and not two and I want to send the data all together and populate the tax table and the tax detail table from the database at the same time.

these are the classes:

```
public class Impuesto
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ImpuestoId { get; set; }  
        public  ICollection<ImpuestoDetalle> ImpuestosDetalle { get; set; } 
        
        public string ClaveProdServ { get; set; }  
        public string ClaveUnidad { get; set; } 
    }
    public class ImpuestoDetalle
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ImpuestoDetalleId { get; set; }
        public TipoImpuesto TipoImpuesto { get; set; }
        public EfectoImpuesto EfectoImpuesto { get; set; }
        public decimal Tasa { get; set; } 
    }
```

in the form these bind-value values come from the tax class:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" @bind-value="@Impuesto.ClaveProdServ" />
```

these values in the same form come from the tax class details:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" @bind-value="@ImpuestoDetalle.Tasa" />
```

Here I save the form data but I only send the values of the tax class to the tax table, I am missing the values of the tax class details:

```
@code {
    private Impuesto Impuesto = new Impuesto();    
    private ImpuestoDetalle ImpuestoDetalle = new ImpuestoDetalle();    

    public async Task GuardarImpuesto()
    {    
        var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post("api/Impuesto", Impuesto);
        @if (httpResponse.Error)
        {
            var body = await httpResponse.GetBody();
            await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeError(body);
        }
        else
        {
            await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeExitoso("Impuesto Agregado");
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/formulario-impuesto");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two objects in one new model which will be used only for the data transfer in the client-server communication.
For example:

Model:

```cs
public class ImpuestoModelo 
{
    public Impuesto Tax { get; set; }
    public ImpuestoDetalle TaxDetails { get; set; }
}
```

The model could be added in the shared project and reused in both Server and Client.

SaveTax:

```cs
public async Task GuardarImpuesto()
{    
    var taxModel = new ImpuestoModelo { Tax = Impuesto, TaxDetails = ImpuestosDetalle };
    var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post("api/Impuesto", taxModel);
    @if (httpResponse.Error)
    {
        var body = await httpResponse.GetBody();
        await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeError(body);
    }
    else
    {
        await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeExitoso("Impuesto Agregado");
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("/formulario-impuesto");
    }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
[Route("api/Impuesto")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveTax(ImpuestoModelo taxModel)
{
    // validation

    // saving in the db
    db.Taxes.Add(taxModel.Tax);
    db.TaxDetails.Add(taxModel.TaxDetails);
}
```

This is a sample API method for ASP.NET Core. You can use another back-end, but the logic will be similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, it worked perfectly, if I was doing something similar but I was missing this line: var taxModel = new ImpuestoModelo { Tax = Impuesto, TaxDetails = ImpuestosDetalle };